# How to block a number in Sony Xperia J

Tags: sony-xperia-j

I intend to block a number that is in my contact list. 
Unfortunately I can't find any option to block it. I was told that I should add it to some Reject list.

When I open the contact and press Menu, I see only 4 options:

- Modify
- Send contact
- Delete contact
- Set as default

Where should I add it to the reject list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shockingly, you can't block calls with Xperia phones.

> Unfortunately it's not possible to do this without installing any 3rd party software. I know that Truecaller has this function if you want to use a 3rd party app.

Source: [official Sony forum](http://talk.sonymobile.com/t5/Xperia-Z1-Z1s/How-to-block-someones-call-and-sms-on-ma-xperia-z1/m-p/799031#M32118)

You need to download 3rd party softwares that are mentioned earlier:

[TrueCaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en)

[Calls Blacklist](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vladlee.easyblacklist&hl=en)

Answer (score 2):

I found the best way to do it:

1. Go to the contact you want to block.
2. Click the contact and then options.
3. Scroll to the bottom and click send calls to voice mail.

Other than that there is no way to block a contact on the Xperia J.

Answer (score 1):

Well, let us try doing this again,

1. Pickup your Sony Xperia J,
2. Open the contact page
3. Select number from the list (i.e. the number you want to blacklist)
4. Press Menu key
5. Add to reject list.

All done I think you are going somewhere wrong, it has to be there ! Let me know if you find it out !

Comment: Should I see the *contacts* page or the *contact's* page? On the contacts page I see 6 options: Import contacts, Backup contacts, Display, Send contacts, Delete contacts, Settings. No Reject list.

Comment: Well, I would say if you keep encountering problem i.e in your  case you are not finding it, try installing and application which can do this for you, I am sure if your tried searching over the PlayStore you are going to find a number of them, or if you want it from my side then try using this one https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.vladlee.easyblacklist&hl=en I will also works the same way.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app called [Truecaller](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.truecaller&hl=en) I think to do this job. You can find it also by typing its name into the search field on the Google Play Store.

Comment: Thanks but I'd prefer the built-in solution. I wonder why it is not available.

Comment: Almost all the android devices doesn't have this feature built-in and I don't know why. Truecaller might help you if you give it a try.

Answer (score -1):

[Caller ID & Block Calls, Texts](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.visinor.phonewarrior) is one app that may work.  You can get it for free in playstore.

Comment: Please include links to the app in your answer.

Comment: It looks like you may have meant "Caller ID & Blocks Calls, Texts" by Phone Warrior.  Editing answer to include link.